# BackGroundWorker и огромные вычисления

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Ознакомился с BackGroundWorker,оказалось что она может мне помочь.

И прочитав несколько примеров решил применить на своей форме

Метод который я хочу вложить в BackGroundWorker

```
public void drawreverse(BackgroundWorker worker, double U, double T, double shag, int frc, int frc1, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                GraphPane panel77 = zedGraphControl2.GraphPane;
                NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
                double t = 0;
                panel77.Title.Text = "Обратное преобразование";
                panel77.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
                panel77.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
                panel77.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsZeroLine = false;
                panel77.XAxis.Title.Text = "f,кГЦ";
                panel77.YAxis.Title.Text = "U(f), мВ*с";
                PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();

                double xmin = frc;
                double xmax = frc1;

                double xmin_limit = -100;
                double xmax_limit = 100;

                double ymin_limit = -20;
                double ymax_limit = 20;

                panel77.XAxis.Cross = 0.0;
                panel77.YAxis.Cross = 0.0;

                panel77.XAxis.Scale.IsSkipFirstLabel = true;
                panel77.XAxis.Scale.IsSkipLastLabel = true;

                panel77.XAxis.Scale.IsSkipCrossLabel = true;
                panel77.YAxis.Scale.IsSkipFirstLabel = true;

                panel77.YAxis.Scale.IsSkipLastLabel = true;
                panel77.YAxis.Scale.IsSkipCrossLabel = true;

                panel77.XAxis.Title.IsVisible = false;
                panel77.YAxis.Title.IsVisible = false;


                for (double fr = frc; fr <= frc1; fr += shag)
                {
                    double resulting = (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(angularFrequency => GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T)) * Math.Cos(angularFrequency * t), 0, frc1);
                    list1.Add(fr, resulting);
                }

                panel77.AddCurve("", list1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);

                panel77.XAxis.Scale.Min = xmin_limit;
                panel77.XAxis.Scale.Max = xmax_limit;

                panel77.YAxis.Scale.Min = ymin_limit;
                panel77.YAxis.Scale.Max = ymax_limit;

                zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
                zedGraphControl2.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

И так код выкладываю по частям.

1-ый вопрос возник в этой части

Учитывая что метод у меня с параметрами как их можно объявить внутри backgroundWorker?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,
                       DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                e.Result = drawreverse(U,  T, shag, frc,frc1, worker, e);
            }
```

В методе ниже проблема с выводом результата.Учитывая что у меня результат это вычисление и построение графика,то я только лишь понял что метод нужно снова вызвать но он опять же у меня с параметрами.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
            object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }              
            else
            {
             drawreverse(U,T,frc,frc1,shag);   
///Здесь судя по МСДН пишут результат но у меня результат построение графиков,как можно его сюда записать?Просто так он мой метод не обработает так как уже ругается на параметры,которые в нём.
            }  
        }
```

UPD:
После того как я объявил переменные U,T,frc,frc1,shag в начале формы возникли другие сложности

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,
                   DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            e.Result = drawreverse(worker, e);
//Ошибка    2   Неявное преобразование типа "void" в "object" невозможно
```

//Здесь конечно непонятно,этот метод работает медленно и я его вкладываю в BackgroundWorker,возвращает он выполнение построения графиков,то есть я не могу его присвоить или double,int.
            }

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
            object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)

        {
            BackgroundWorker worker;
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }           
            else
            {
                drawreverse(worker, e); //
Ошибки:
Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs" в "System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs" невозможно
```

Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "MainFormProg1.FurierTransformReverse.drawreverse(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов
                }
            }

И  в кнопке вызова,то есть я нажимаю кнопку и начинаются вычисление(в том числе и метода,который я запихнул в backGroundWorker)

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                highestPercentageReached = 0;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(numberToCompute);
                BackgroundWorker worker;

                int T = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                int U = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                double shag = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
                int frc = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
                int frc1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
                int frequency, counter;
                List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
                    for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
                    {
                    values.Add(reverstrans(U, frequency, T, frc, frc1,shag));
                    }
                    values.ForEach(x1 => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x1.Real, x1.Imaginary));
                    drawgraph();
                    drawreverse(worker, e);
    Ошибки:
    Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "System.EventArgs" в "System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs" невозможно    
Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "MainFormProg1.FurierTransformReverse.drawreverse(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов   
               }
```

UPD

Снова возникли проблемы при компиляции

Вот я объявил класс и сделал его public

public class CustomParams
        {
            double U,T,shag;
            int frc, frc1;
        }

Затем в этом методе он почему то ругается на уровень защиты у полей U,T

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var param = e.Argument as CustomParams;
            drawreverse(param.U, param.T, param.frc1, param.frc, param.shag);
        }
```

Метод  `public void drawreverse(double U,double T,int frc,int frc1,double shag`)`он у меня`public`

Теперь я вызываю метод где  хочу запустить BackGround,ругается на params,заменил на param и в итоге мои величины снова запрещены из за доступа защиты.

По поводу 0,я внизу в строке написал почему я присвоил.

Возникла большая путанница с переменными,я их ввожу с клавиатуры а получается я ещё их должен создать?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int T = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int U = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    double shag = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
    int frc = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
    int frc1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
    int frequency, counter;
    List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
        BackgroundWorker worker;
    var param = new CustomParams();
    params.U = 0;
    params.T = 0;
    params.frc = 0;
    params.frc1 = 0;
    params.shag = 0;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(param);

    for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
    {
        values.Add(reverstrans(U, frequency, T, frc, frc1, shag));
    }
    values.ForEach(x1 => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x1.Real, x1.Imaginary));
    drawgraph(U,T,frc,frc1,shag);
    drawreverse(U,T, frc,frc1,shag);
           }
```

Comment: Я ввожу U,T,frc,frc1,shag через Текстбокс.
И уже на основе того что я ввёл происходят вычисления то есть я ввёл например U=1 и всё U=1 учавствует во всех формулах где она упоминается

Comment: что-то вы намудрили :) объясните, вы хотите сделать так, что нажимая на кнопку, происходят вычисления и результат отображается на графике, при этом вычисления вы хотите делать в фоне через BW, чтобы форма не подтормаживала, верно?

Comment: Да я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки происходил расчёт и всё это отображалось на progressBar и не тормозила форма.

Так как у меня там значения доходят от 5000 тысяч итераций до 200 тысяч  в цикле(так по заданию просто) и время расчёта 5-10 минут что не устраивает меня.

так как пока программа считает она зависает

Answer (score 1):

1) Для передачи всех ваших аргументов в  воркер, при запуске передавайте в качестве аргумента метода RunWorkerAsync.

```
class CustomParams 
{
  double U;
  //...и так далее
}
```

Использование:

```
var param = new CustomParams();
//params.U = ...
worker.RunWorkerAsync(param);
```

В DoWork использовать можно так:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,
                   DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   var param = e.Argument as CustomParams;
   drawreverse(param.U /* и т.д. */);
}
```

Сигнатуру drawreverse соответственно лучше поменять на

```
public void drawreverse(double U, double T, double shag, int frc, int frc1) {/* ... */}
```

2)Метод `drawreverse` у вас указан как `void`. Это означает, что он не имеет возвращаемого значения. Определитесь для начала, что именно должен делать этот метод, что должен возвращать. Скорее всего, коллекцию вычисленных точек. Отрисовывать сам график в другом потоке не советую, ибо может возникнуть множество проблем(взаимодействие с GUI в c# должно происходить в том же потоке, в котором оно было создано).

Comment: Метод drawreverse считает точки на основе введёного U,T,frc,frc1,shag,которые будут изображены на график

Там же в методе происходит получение координаты икс и уже оно вместе с результатом метода reverstrans(которое в цикле) рисует график.

Поэтому я и не могу их разделить они у меня как единое целое.

Comment: var param = new CustomParams();
//params.U = ...
worker.RunWorkerAsync(param);

Этот код я должен реализовать при нажатии кнопки или же подставить в метод?

Comment: RunWorkerAsync - запускает выполнение метода. Следовательно, данный код должен выполняться при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: А что вам мешает передавать посчитанные точки как результат выполнения метода drawreverse? Потом уже в backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted можно будет без опасений рисовать график.

Comment: они привязаны к графику,ZedGraph не особо позволяет отдельно что-то там вычислять
Я вызывал отдельно метод но увы там другие значения,а если привяжу к ZedGraphControl то все результаты совпадают с поставленной задачей.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (o, args) => Work();
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Work()
{
    // тут считывайте данные с формы
    // проводите вычисления
    // выводите результат
}
```

Comment: К сожалению выскочило исключение на этой строке

values.ForEach(x1 => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x1.Real, x1.Imaginary));

Само исключение звучит так
Исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" возникло в System.Windows.Forms.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя

Дополнительные сведения: Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'dataGridView1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан.